# Show duration between start time and now taking into account last pause

Tags: javascript

I have a simple function that displays the duration between a start time and now.

It uses MomentJS to work out the diff like so:

```
duration = moment.duration(moment(new Date()).diff(Journey.startTime));
```

However a user can pause the Journey that this duration works with and therefore when the Journey is resumed again... the timer will suddenly jump as it's working out the duration from the start and doesn't take into account the pause/resume.

To take this pause into account I record the date when the Journey is paused and then use that to work out the new duration like so:

```
if(Journey.pauseTime) {
    let newDate = moment(Journey.startTime).add(Journey.pauseTime - Journey.startTime, 'ms').toDate();
    duration = moment.duration(moment(new Date()).diff(newDate));
} else {
    duration = moment.duration(moment(new Date()).diff(Journey.startTime));
}
```

However depending on how fast the Journey is paused/resumed as well as if the Journey is left paused for a long period and resume again the duration jumps around...

I'm not quite sure why this because the startTime is static (once started) and taking that from whatever the new pauseTime is should return a date to use for working out the duration... but assume I've missed a trick here I can't see...

Comment: Don't you also need a resume time? And what if the journey was paused multiple times?

Answer (score 1):

I would do it with vanilla javascript:

```js
let timestamps = [];

function pauseResume() {
    timestamps.push(Date.now());
}

function getTime() {
  let time = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < timestamps.length; i++) {
    if(i % 2 == 0) {
      time -= timestamps[i];
    } else {
      time += timestamps[i];
    }
  }
  if (timestamps.length % 2 == 1) {
    time += Date.now();
  }
  console.log(time / 1000 + "s");
  return time;
}
```

```html
<button onClick="pauseResume()">Pause/Resume</button>
<button onClick="getTime()">getTime</button>
```